# JQuery Function in Bootstrap 5 AJAX Modal NOT Getting NEW Values

Tags: jquery, validation, bootstrap-5

I have a small form in a Bootstrap 5 modal that is loaded dynamically with data in the fields. The user can change the values and submit the form which goes through fine, but when trying to do some validation onsubmit, it doesn't show the new field values and only the original values.

Opening the Modal

```
function viewModal(url,size='lg',fields='') {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        success: function(response){ 
            $('.modal-content').html(response);
            $('#genericModal' + size.toUpperCase()).modal('show'); 
        }
    });
}
```

Viewing the Modal

```
<!-- Modal Header -->
<div class="modal-header bg-success text-white">
    <h4 class="modal-title">@if(isset($address)){{'Edit'}}@else{{'Add'}}@endif an Address</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
</div>
<form id="formAddress" action="/v3/modals/address" class="needs-validation" method="post">
    @csrf
    @if(isset($address))@method('PATCH')@endif
    @if(isset($address))<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="{{$address->id}}">@endif
    <input type="hidden" id="urlID" name="urlID" value="{{$applicant->urlID}}">
    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                <label for="streetLine1" class="form-label"><strong>Street Line 1 *</strong></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="quickCheckField('streetLine1')" id="streetLine1" name="streetLine1" placeholder="First line of address" value="@if(isset($address)){{$address->streetLine1}}@endif" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                <label for="streetLine2" class="form-label"><strong>Street Line 2</strong></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="quickCheckField('streetLine2')" id="streetLine2" name="streetLine2" placeholder="Second line of address" value="@if(isset($address)){{$address->streetLine2}}@endif">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                <label for="town" class="form-label"><strong>Town or City</strong></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="quickCheckField('town')" id="town" name="town" placeholder="Name of Town or City" value="@if(isset($address)){{$address->town}}@endif" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                <label for="postcode" class="form-label"><strong>Post Code</strong></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" onchange="quickCheckField('postcode')" id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Post Code or Zip" value="@if(isset($address)){{$address->postcode}}@endif" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                <label for="countryID" class="form-label"><strong>Country</strong></label>
                <select class="form-control"  onchange="quickCheckField('countryID')" id="countryID" name="countryID" required>
                    <option value="">Please select...</option>
                    <option value="1">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option value="105">Ireland</option>
                    <option disabled>----------</option>
                    @foreach ($countries as $field)<option value="{{ $field->id }}"@if(isset($address))@if($field->id==$address->countryID){{'selected'}}@endif @endif>{{$field->countryName}}</option>@endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                <label for="dateFromM" class="form-label"><strong>Date Lived at Address From *</strong></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <select class="reqField form-control" onchange="quickCheckField('dateFromM')" id="dateFromM" name="dateFromM" required>
                        <option value="">Month</option>
                        @for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)<option value="{{str_pad($i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)}}"@if(isset($address))@if(str_pad($i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)==substr($address->dateFrom,5,2)){{'selected'}}@endif @endif>{{date_format(date_create("01-".$i."-2000"), "M")}} ({{str_pad($i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)}})</option>@endfor
                    </select>
                    <select class="reqField form-control" onchange="quickCheckField('dateFromY')" id="dateFromY" name="dateFromY" required>
                        <option value="">Year</option>
                        @for($i=(date('Y'));$i>=(date('Y')-110);$i--)<option value="{{$i}}"@if(isset($address))@if($i==substr($address->dateFrom,0,4)){{'selected'}}@endif @endif>{{$i}}</option>@endfor
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                <label for="dateTillM" class="form-label"><strong>Date Lived at Address Until *</strong></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <select class="reqField form-control" onchange="quickCheckField('dateTillM')" id="dateTillM" name="dateTillM" required>
                        <option value="">Month</option>
                        @for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)<option value="{{str_pad($i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)}}"@if(isset($address))@if(str_pad($i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)==substr($address->dateTill,5,2)){{'selected'}}@endif @endif>{{date_format(date_create("01-".$i."-2000"), "M")}} ({{str_pad($i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)}})</option>@endfor
                    </select>
                    <select class="reqField form-control" onchange="quickCheckField('dateTillY')" id="dateTillY" name="dateTillY" required>
                        <option value="">Year</option>
                        @for($i=(date('Y'));$i>=(date('Y')-110);$i--)<option value="{{$i}}"@if(isset($address))@if($i==substr($address->dateTill,0,4)){{'selected'}}@endif @endif>{{$i}}</option>@endfor
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formErrorMessage" class="text-danger text-center"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        @if(isset($address))<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="btnDeleteName" onclick="confirmDelete()">Delete Address</button>@endif
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveAddress">Save Address</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Validation Javascript

```
<script>
    $("#btnSaveAddress").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#formErrorMessage").text("");

        $reqFields = [ "streetLine1", "town", "postcode", "countryID", "dateFromM", "dateFromY", "dateTillM", "dateTillY" ];

        $passedValidation = true;

        $.each($reqFields, function( i, fieldID ) {
            if ($("#" + fieldID).val() == "") {
                $passedValidation = false;
                $("#" + fieldID).removeClass("is-valid");
                $("#" + fieldID).addClass("is-invalid");
            } else {
                $("#" + fieldID).removeClass("is-invalid");
                $("#" + fieldID).addClass("is-valid");
            }
        });

        if ($("#dateFromY").val() + $("#dateFromM").val() >= $("#dateTillY").val() + $("#dateTillM").val()) {
            $passedValidation = false;
            $("#dateTillM").removeClass("is-valid");
            $("#dateTillM").addClass("is-invalid");
            $("#dateTillY").removeClass("is-valid");
            $("#dateTillY").addClass("is-invalid");
            $("#formErrorMessage").text("The Date Till must be after the Date From");
        }

        if ($passedValidation == true) {
            $("#formAddress").trigger("submit");
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have trawled Google and Stack looking for an answer, but I can't seem to find one. I've tried explicitly referencing the fields including the formID in the calls, but nothing shows the new values.

Comment: Check that you don't have duplicated IDs.  Code like `$("#"+fieldID)` will return only the *first* matching element in the DOM.  If you have eg a display form with an element with that ID then one in the modal, your code will pick up the display form's input, not the modal's.  You can check by adding `console.log($("[id='" + fieldID + "']").length)` inside your `$.each`.   If any are not 1, that will be your issue.   You can fix this by changing the `$("#"+fieldID)` by prefixing with your modal id or class, eg `$("#genericModal").find("#" + fieldID)`

Comment: The above (multiple inputs with the same ID) could also be caused as you seem to have multiple modals, each loading content.